# Why is my jQuery condition not working?

Tags: php, jquery

I am using ajax to insert data into a MySQL database with php. Once the data is succesfully inserted into the database I want to trigger an alert using a condition.

I can't figure out why my condition in jquery is not working. The php side of things is working fine and returns the 'success' response which I can see in an `alert()` but not when I use the condition. 
Hopefully someone can show me what I have gotten wrong, thanks.

The jquery

```
 submitHandler: function (form) { 

var formdata = $("#edit_post").serialize();
    $.post('edit_upload.php', formdata,
           function(data){

            if(data =="success"){ //alert if records inserted
            alert(data);
   }
});
return false;
}
```

edit_upload.php

```
//Update Database 
$stmt = $db_conx->prepare('UPDATE tbl_uploads SET title=?, detail=? WHERE id=?');
$stmt->bind_param('sss',$title,$detail,$id);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->execute()) { //true
echo 
         'success';
}

else{ echo "error"; }
```

Comment: Try `if (data.trim() == "success")`, or better yet return a boolean value via JSON

Comment: Use the debugger built into your browser to stop on the `if (data == "success")` line, look at the contents of the `data` variable, and find out. Probably, it has whitespace on one or both ends of the string.

Comment: Open the developer console (typically F12) and check the network traffic for the actual content of the response to decide what's actually happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely that the issue is being caused by some whitespace being added to the returned string. You can remove this by using `trim()`:

```
$.post('edit_upload.php', formdata, function(data) {
  if (data.trim() == 'success') {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

You should note though that it would be much better practice, and far less error prone, to return a boolean value via JSON, like this:

```php
$stmt = $db_conx->prepare('UPDATE tbl_uploads SET title=?, detail=? WHERE id=?');
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $title, $detail, $id);
echo json_encode(array('success' => $stmt->execute());
```

```js
$.post('edit_upload.php', formdata, function(data) {
  if (data.success) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```